# Chern class in Bott-Tu

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I've met some trouble in understanding Chern class. I first touch the Chern class in classyfying space of characteristic class. For $\pi:E\rightarrow X$ and we have such relationship:$$Vect^n_{\Bbb C}(X) \cong [X,Gr_n(C^{\infty})] \cong [X,BU(n)]$$ so for $f:M\rightarrow Gr_n(C^{\infty})\cong BU(n)$, we define the Chern class via pullbuck $f^*:H^*(BU(n),\Bbb Z)\rightarrow H^*(M,\Bbb Z)$. Intuitively speaking, this apprroach classfies the complex vector bundle.

It seems that Bott&Tu uses Grothendieck's approach by constructing line bundle and the first Chern class We then define the projectivization of vector bundle $\pi:P(E)\rightarrow M$, more precisely we have the taotological exact sequence $$0\rightarrow S \rightarrow \pi^{-1}E\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 0$$ here $\pi^{-1}E$ is the vector bundle over $P(E)$; $S$ is the universal bundle over $P(E)$ and $Q$ is the quotient bundle.

We then set $x=c_1(S^*)$ where $S^*$ is called hyperplane bundle which is dual to $S$ and Bott&Tu says the cohomology ring of $H^*(P(E))=H^*(M)[x]/(x^n+c_1(E)x^{n-1}+...+c_n(E))$

Here the Chern clss is defined via projective bundle and I can't undertstand it and its relationship between the way given by characteristic class?

More precisely, the relationship between Grassmannian manifold and projective bundle?

Comment: Have you tried taking the projective bundle of the univeral bundle over the Grassmannian? A vector bundle morphism induces a morphism of projective bundle, so now you can pull back the universal 'projective Chern classes' and the 'Grasmmannian Chern classes' and compare the two.

Comment: @Tyrone I see,I take the projective bundle of $\gamma^{n}$ over $Gr_n$. And I finally get a homormorphism $\pi^*:H^*(Gr_n(C^{\infty}))\rightarrow H^*(P(\gamma^n))$, if my understanding is not wrong, we have  $f:M\rightarrow Gr_n(C^{\infty})$ gets a new projective bundle $p:P(E)=f^{-1}(P(\gamma^n))\rightarrow M$ and induces a  new bundle morhism $H^*(P(E))\rightarrow H^*(M)$ which corresponds to the definition by Bott&Tu.

Comment: Yes, this was my suggestion. Of course the cohomology of $H^*(P(\gamma))$ is given by the formula in terms of the universal chern classes $c_k=c_k(\gamma)$, so its not difficult to see from here that the two definitions are different sides of the same coin.

Comment: @Tyrone By the way, "A vector bundle morphism induces a morphism of projective bundle",is it related with Chow theorem?